# bogus_host_without_reverse_dns from server's own IP

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, varnish

I see a lot of bogus_host_without_reverse_dns originating from server's own IP in Apache status.

```
405-0   28180   0/20/542    _   0.07    33  147 0.0 0.00    0.42    127.127.127.127 bogus_host_without_reverse_dns  NULL
```

Sometimes there is 700 such request in server-status. (the server IP was replaced before posting here)

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: The IP address doesn't have reverse DNS? Did you actually check?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've checked on this site: http://www.digwebinterface.com/?type=Reverse and the IP address is listed and has the reverse IP entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this when testing out ssl on a site that was using a wildcard cert. Just add the DNS into your /etc/hosts file and restart apache. Make sure to remove this when you are done testing.